# Could an employee be held liable for taking parts meant for another assembly line?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law

If foreman A of assembly line AA took parts meant for a different assembly line BB for their own crews to use, which would help them meet their production quota but hurt foreman B and their crew, could A be held liable in a civil action or criminal charge? Both A and B and their crews work for the same organization.

Comment: Do A and B get any monetary bonuses based on the work outputs of their crews?

Answer (score 5):

The parts are owned by Z, the company. The usual definition of "theft" is as in RCW 9a.56.020:

> (a) To wrongfully obtain or exert unauthorized control over the
> property or services of another or the value thereof, with intent to
> *deprive him or her of such property* or services; or (b) By color or aid of deception to obtain control over the property or services of
> another or the value thereof, with intent to *deprive him or her* of
> such property or services; or (c) To appropriate lost or misdelivered
> property or services of another, or the value thereof, with intent to
> *deprive him or her* of such property or services.

In moving property within the company from one part to another, B has not been deprived of its property. The company might fire A for unauthorized use of company property, but this is not a legal matter, it is an employment matter. B cannot sue A, although B might sue Z if B was punished for not meeting quota, Z knew of the the reason for not meeting quota, and A's motivation was illegally discriminatory ([Perez v. DDR](https://casetext.com/case/perez-v-developers-diversified-realty-corp)).